# Shiny Modules with Observes and reactiveValues

Tags: r, module, shiny, reactive-programming

I have been trying to reconstruct the following simplistic Shiny app using [modules](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) since I believe that will be the best way to organize this code inside a much larger application where I will use these kinds of linked-slider-numeric inputs in many places.

However, I cannot figure out how to achieve the same kind of functionality from within a module.

Here's an example app that works exactly as intended, but not using modules:

```
library(shiny)

# Let's build a linked Slider and Numeric Input

server <- function(input, output) {

  values <- reactiveValues(numval=1) 

  observe({
    values$numval <- input$slider
  })
  observe({
    values$numval <- input$number
  })

  output$slide <- renderUI({
    sliderInput(
      inputId = 'slider'
      ,label = 'SN'
      ,min = 0
      ,max = 10
      ,value = values$numval
    )})

  output$num <- renderUI({
    numericInput(
      inputId = 'number'
      ,label = 'SN'
      ,value = values$numval
      ,min = 0
      ,max = 10
    )
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput('slide'),
  uiOutput('num')
)


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here's my attempt. (Note that "mortalityRate" and associated strings are just an example of the variable name(s) I'll be using later). I have tried several variations on this attempt, but inevitably I get errors, usually indicating I'm doing something that can only be done inside a reactive context:

```
numericSliderUI <- function(id, label = "Enter value", min = 1, max = 40, value) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    sliderInput(inputId = paste0(ns(id), "Slider"), label = label, min = min, max = max, value = value),
    numericInput(inputId = paste0(ns(id), "Numeric"), label = label, min = min, max = max, value = value)
  )
}

numericSlider <-
  function(input,
           output,
           session,
           value,
           mortalityRateSlider,
           mortalityRateNumeric
           ) {

  values <- reactiveValues(mortalityRate = value())
  observe({
      values[['mortalityRate']] <- mortalityRateSlider()
  })
  observe({
    values[['mortalityRate']] <- mortalityRateNumeric()
  })
  return( reactive( values[['mortalityRate']] ) )
}

library(shiny)
# source("modules.R") # I keep the modules in a separate file, but they're just pasted above for convenience here on StackOverflow.

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput('mortalityRate')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues(mortalityRate = 1)
  mortalityRateValue <- callModule(
    numericSlider,
    id = 'mortalityRate',
    value = values[['mortalityRate']],
    mortalityRateSlider = reactive( input$mortalityRateSlider ),
    mortalityRateNumeric = reactive( input$mortalityRateNumeric )
  )
  values[['mortalityRate']] <- reactive( mortalityRateValue() )
  output$mortalityRate <- renderUI(numericSliderUI('mortalityRate', value = values[['mortalityRate']]))
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I know that I must be doing something wrong with the reactiveValues and the way I'm using the observe statements inside the module, but this is my best attempt at using the module structure, so any help figuring out what I'm doing wrong would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm confused about your use of both the `tagList` in your UI module and a `renderUI`. Is there a reason in your larger app that you need both? Generally you'd want one or the other...

Comment: The documentation for ?renderUI gives an example that uses a renderUI wrapped around a tagList, so unless the documentation itself is a bad practice, I'm not sure why I shouldn't do that. I do that because I want to construct a module which renders both a sliderInput and a numericInput which are linked to each other in the value they represent.

Comment: Yes, that is good (necessary) practice - my question was poorly worded. Putting the `tagList` in the UI module is a direct (non-responsive) way of setting up the UI, and I was confused about whether you wanted it that way or specified through a `renderUI`. I realized after asking that you needed a `renderUI` to link the inputs in a responsive fashion. Note the inclusion of the `tagList` in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is working code. There are a variety of changes, so I'll direct you to [this Github page](https://gist.github.com/FrissAnalytics/3567fb939590d55b108b) that also sets up a structure for using `renderUI` with modules. In general, I think the problems in your code involved trying to define reactive values inside the `callModule` function, and in passing the values of the sliders and numeric box back and forth.

Other features of using modules are that in your actual UI call, you need to call the UI module, where in turn you can call `uiOutput`. Inside `renderUI` is where you can set up the inputs. Additionally, inside modules you don't need the session namespaces, but you do need to wrap those ids in `session$ns()` to ensure they work across modules.

**UI and Server Modules:**

```
numericSliderUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns('mortalityRate'))
}

numericSlider <- function(input, output, session) {

    values <- reactiveValues(mortalityRate = 1)

    observe({
      values[['mortalityRate']] <- input$Slider
    })

    observe({
      values[['mortalityRate']] <- input$Numeric
    })

    output$mortalityRate <- renderUI(
      tagList(
        sliderInput(inputId = session$ns("Slider"), label = "Enter value:", min = 1, max = 40, value = values[['mortalityRate']]),
        numericInput(inputId = session$ns("Numeric"), label = "Enter value:", min = 1, max = 40, value = values[['mortalityRate']])
      )
    )

    return(list(value = reactive({values[['mortalityRate']]})))
  }
```

**UI and Server functions:**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericSliderUI('mortalityRate')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mortalityRateValue <- callModule(numericSlider, 'mortalityRate')
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I don't know why I didn't think to put a renderUI inside the module and a uiOutput in the the numericSliderUI. Thank you very much for helping me with this. In particular, thanks for highlighting the need for session$ns. I wouldn't have caught that on my own before now.